# Master Transmuter + token artifacts

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Master Transmuter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220510) reads:

> {U}, {T}, Return an artifact you control to its owner’s hand: You may put an artifact card from your hand onto the battlefield.

Can Master Transmuter return a token artifact to your hand (which causes it to cease to exist) and then put an artifact card from hand to the battlefield (like [Metalwork Colossus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=417795))

Comment: Technically, whatever object you return to your hand ceases to exist, token or not.[CR 400.7]  (The fact that the new object in your hand also ceases to exist in the case of a token is irrelevant.)

Comment: And so does the mana you payed to cover the {U} cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the artifact was returned to your hand. The fact it then ceased to exist doesn't matter, you still returned it to your hand.